# Spectrum of $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ with respect to space of continuous periodic functions on $[0,2\pi]$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, spectral-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}$ denote the Banach space of all continuous functions $f: [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(0) = f(2\pi)$. Let $A$ denote the operator
$$Af = -f'', \qquad \text{Dom}(A) = \{ f \in \mathcal{B} : f \in C^2[0,2\pi] \}.$$

> I would like to find the spectrum of $A$.

So far, I've been trying to compute the spectrum by hand, and I conjecture that $\text{spec}(A)$ is $\{n^2 : n = 0,1, 2, \dots\}$. We get one inclusion simply by noticing that, for each $n = 0, 1, 2, \dots$, $n^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with periodic eigenfunction $e^{inx}$.

Showing the other inclusion is where I have gotten stuck. By factoring 
$$-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}- \lambda^2 = (D_x - \lambda)(D_x + \lambda), \qquad D_x = \frac{1}{i} \frac{d}{dx}, \, \lambda \neq 1, 2, \dots $$ 
and using the integrating factor method twice, we find that the solution $u$ to the equation
$$(A - \lambda^2)u = f \in \mathcal{B},$$
is given by
$$u(x) = c_2 e^{-i\lambda t} + \frac{c_1}{i2\lambda}e^{i\lambda t} + F(x), $$
for some $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ and where
$$F(x) = \int_0^x e^{i2\lambda t} \int^s_0 e^{-i\lambda t} f(t) dt ds.$$

So the above expression for $u$ is our proposed formula for $(A - \lambda^2)^{-1}f$, but it remains to show that $(A - \lambda^2)^{-1}$ is bounded and that $u$ can indeed be made periodic.

Requiring that $u$ be periodic gives rise to a linear system to solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$. It appears this system has a unique solution unless $\lambda$ is an integer or half-integer. So, it may be that the spectrum consists of more than eigenvalues above. But I'm not sure how to decide if the half-integers are indeed in the spectrum or not.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you note any eigenvector of $A$ must be a solution of $-f'' - \lambda f=0$, all of which are in the form $f(t) = c_1 e^{i\sqrt\lambda t}+ c_2 e^{-i\sqrt \lambda t}$. Additionally we must impose periodicity of this solution, which becomes
$$f(0)=c_1+c_2 \overset!= f(2\pi) =  c_1 e^{i2\pi\sqrt \lambda }+c_2e^{-i2\pi\sqrt\lambda}.$$
Re-arrange and this is the same condition as:
$$c_1(1-e^{i2\pi\sqrt\lambda})= c_2(e^{-i2\pi\sqrt\lambda}-1)$$

In the event that $\sqrt\lambda$ is an integer any choice of $c_1, c_2$ yields a solution and there is a two dimensional eingenspace. However if $\sqrt\lambda$ is not an integer, then any choice of $c_1$ with $c_2= -c_1\,\frac{1-e{i2\pi\sqrt\lambda}}{1-e^{-i2\pi\sqrt\lambda}}$ also yields a solution and the eigenspace is one dimensional.

Thus $A-\lambda$ is never injective and the spectrum is all of $\Bbb C$. If you want to recover a discrete spectrum you need boundary condition $f(0)=0=f(2\pi)$ .

Comment: Hmmm I thought that the spectrum of the laplacian on the torus was discrete (and that exponentials form an eigenbasis). Where is the catch?

Comment: @lcv Note that $C^\infty[0,2\pi]$ with periodic boundary condition is not the same as $C^\infty(S^1)$. As such the periodic solutions you find here actually have "jumps" in the derivatives if you glue the two ends together and are not eigenfunctions of the laplacian of $S^1$. Some of these problems come from the fact that you shouldn't really look $\Delta$ on the space $C(X)$ but rather on $L^2(X)$, where you can find a really good domain for which $\Delta$ is self-adjoint ($X$ compact manifold).

Comment: I see many thanks. So this is an important caveat. Unfortunately the notation itself is misleading or at least dangerous as with any (unbounded) operator one needs to carefully associate a domain as you also essentially are saying. It may not be entirely clear if with $C^{\infty}[0, 2\pi]$ with PBC one means that discontinuities in the derivatives are allowed or not (which rules out your second condition). +1 and thanks.